# UITableViewCell with autolayout left margin different on iPhone and iPad

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout, margin

I am using a grouped `UITableView` with static cells for an options screen/scene. Everything is done in Xcode 6.1 / iOS 8.1.x / Storyboard using Autolayout. Within the table groups there are mixed types of cells and there are two types that cause me problems:

1. Cells with custom style and
2. Cells with style "Right Detail"

On cell #1 I can set a constraint for the left margin between the label and the leading container. On cell #2 I cannot set any constraints in Interface Builder as far as I know. I have set the left margin on the label in cell #1 so it aligns with the label in cell #2. Everything looks fine on an iPhone, but if I show the same table on an iPad where the size of the table view's container is half the screen size, cell #2 gets more margin (dynamically?) while cell #1 maintains the absolute margin I set in the constraints. I also tried to change the left margin in cell #1 with the attribute "relative to margin" but to no avail.

iPhone:

[image: Table on iPhone]

iPad (with tableview width = 1/2 screen size)

[image: Table on iPad]

So the question is: How do I set the constraints for the label in cell #1 so that it aligns like cell #2.

Here is also a link to a Xcode 6.1 sample project demonstrating the problem. Run on iPhone and iPad to see the difference:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5252156/Code/tableViewTest.zip

This question might be related to [Layout static table cell for iPhone and iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16619435/layout-static-table-cell-for-iphone-and-ipad), but it might also differ for iOS 8 since everything is supposed to be adaptive now. That's why I decided to post this question anyway.

Answer (score 159, accepted):

### How to fix it

After fighting with the apple bug reporting team with many sample projects and screenshots and dissecting [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29712427/4552438), I've found that the solution to have your custom-style cells behave consistently regarding their margins and be just like the default UITableViewCells, you have to do the following (mostly based on [Becky's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30990801/4552438), I've highlighted what's different and what made it work for me) :

1. Select your cell's **content view** in IB
2. Go to the Size Inspector
3. In the Layout Margins section, **check Preserve Superview Margins** (do not click the plus-sign)

   [image: Checking preserve superview margins]
4. (And here's the key) Do the same **for the cell itself** (the content view's parent if you will)

   [image: The cell and not the content view this time]
5. Setup your constraints as follows : Label.Leading = Superview.Leading Margin (with a constant of 0)

   [image: Setting the constraint for the custom cell's label]

Now all your cells will have their label consistent with the default cells! This works for me in Xcode 7 and up and it includes the fix mentioned in the thread I referred to. IB and the simulator should now show properly aligned labels.

[image: Final result in the simulator]

You could also do some of this programmatically, for example in the View Controller's class :

```
cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = true
cell.contentView.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = true
```

Or you could have it set up by calling UIAppearance once at startup (I only know Swift, sorry) :

```
UITableViewCell.appearance().preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = true
UITableViewCell.appearance().contentView.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = true
```

---

### How and why it works

As [Ethan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27420888/uitableviewcell-with-autolayout-left-margin-different-on-iphone-and-ipad/31133547#comment63721997_31133547) kindly pointed out, Apple's own documentation on UIView describes `preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins` as follows :

> When the value of this property is `true`, the superview’s margins are also considered when laying out content. This margin affects layouts where the distance between the edge of a view and its superview is smaller than the corresponding margin. For example, you might have a content view whose frame precisely matches the bounds of its superview. When any of the superview’s margins is inside the area represented by the content view and its own margins, UIKit adjusts the content view’s layout to respect the superview’s margins. The amount of the adjustment is the smallest amount needed to ensure that content is also inside the superview’s margins.

Therefore, if you want your cell's content to align with the **TableView's** margins (it's great-grandparent if you will), you need to have your content's two ascendants, Content View and the Table Cell itself, preserve the margins of their own superview.

Why this isn't default behavior surprises me : I feel like most developers who don't want to customize everything would expect this "inheritance" by default.

Comment: Yep, just checked it, exists in Xcode 7 but not in Xcode 6.3. So the programmatic way, for example in AppDelegate, is the best way for you.

Comment: Typo: preserveSuperviewMargins should be preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins

Comment: Yep, fixed it and the otherwise completely incomplete first snippet. I was apparently too happy to have fixed my own issue to care to check for typos :)

Comment: Can you be more specific on what doesn't work? Are the margins too narrow or too large?

Comment: So I tried it on the 8.1 simulator and indeed, the margins are too narrow, meaning that the superview's layout margins are **not** preserved... However this is a bug that Apple has fixed in 8.3 and somehow fixed again in iOS 9.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I meant. Definitely an Apple bug on iOS 8.1/8.2.

Comment: Just updated to Xcode 7 and voilà it worked like a charm in IB. Thanks!

Comment: If anyone is having issues with this having updated their previously working Xcode 6.x iOS 8.x app to Xcode 7 and iOS 9, THIS WORKS! #lifesaver

Comment: If you look at preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins in Apple's UIView docs, I think what it is basically doing is adjusting the content view to sit inside of it's superview's margins. So, effectively, if you constrain a label inside the content view to the content view's margins, it will also add in the superview's margins if this flag is YES. In other words, if the content view's margins are 15 and the superview's are 5, the total margin you're constraining the label to is 20. And apparently the superview's margins can change from device to device, which it seems is the root of this issue.

Comment: `preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins` is `true` by default for `UITableViewCell` in iOS 10.

Comment: @Manuel Thanks for that comment, I was trying to figure out why my layout was perfect in iOS 11 but broken when I went back to 9.

Comment: "Why this isn't default behavior surprises me" - so true! It's not obvious that it's `true` in iOS 10 because the checkboxes aren't ticked.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the hint! Was struggling with the exact same issue while working with UITableViewCells on iOS >= 11 and iOS < 11 where margins seem to have changed. Preserving superview margins fortunately did the trick.

Answer (score 7):

I ran in the same problem as you did and came up with a solution.

First, a little background: Since iOS 8, default table view cells respect the cell's `layoutMargins` to adapt for different traits (aka screens aka devices). For instance, layout margins on all iPhones (except iPhone 6 Plus when shown in a form sheet) are `{8, 16, 8, 16}`. On iPad they're `{8, 20, 8, 20}`. So now we know that there 4 pixels difference, which most likely your custom table view cell doesn't respect.

Your table view cell subclass needs to adapt the left margin constraint when layoutMargins change.

Here's the relevant code snippet:

```
 - (void)layoutMarginsDidChange
{
    [super layoutMarginsDidChange];

    self.leftLayoutMarginConstraint.constant = self.layoutMargins.left;
    self.rightLayoutMarginConstraint.constant = self.layoutMargins.right;
}
```

Adapting to the layout margins in code enables you getting always the right padding for your title label.

You may also take a look at one of my UITableViewCell subclasses that already respect layoutMargins: https://github.com/bhr/BHRExtensions/blob/master/BHRExtensions/Utilities/BHRTitleAndValueTableCell.m

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! Two remarks to the answer: (1) I am not using a custom table view cell but a static cell in Xcode so I would have to create a subclass first and asign it to all cells int the settings table. (2) The code snippet you provide is only partially helpful in this case as the left- and rightLayoutMarginConstraint properties belong to your subclass and not to UITableViewCell. So the snippet does not work as it is. If someone else is interested in the solution one has to look at you code on GitHub. But still thank you for your pointings!

Answer (score 5):

After reading through the existing answers and not finding an obvious programmatic solution, I did some more digging and now have a good answer for anyone else facing this issue.

First off, it's not necessary to set `preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins` to the cell's view or content view as [other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31133547/39155) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30990801/39155) imply. While the default value is `false`, changing it to `true` had no noticeable effect that I could see.

The key for making this actually work is the `layoutMarginsGuide` property on `UIView`. Using this value, we can just easily pin the `leadingAnchor` of any subview to the `leadingAnchor` of the guide. Here's how it looks in code (and may very well be what IB is doing behind the scenes as in [Jonas's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31133547/39155)).

In a `UITableViewCell` subclass, you would do something like this:

```
override func updateConstraints() {
    let margins = contentView.layoutMarginsGuide
    let leading = margins.leadingAnchor
    subview1.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(leading).active = true
    subview2.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(leading).active = true

    super.updateConstraints()
}
```

**Swift 4.1 update**

```
override func updateConstraints() {
    let margins = contentView.layoutMarginsGuide
    let leading = margins.leadingAnchor
    subview1.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leading).isActive = true
    subview2.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leading).isActive = true

    super.updateConstraints()
}
```

That's all! If you're developing for iOS versions pre-iOS 9, you'll need to substitute out the layout anchors and use the `layoutMargins` inset instead.

---

Note: I wrote a library to make the anchor pinning a little prettier, if you'd prefer a cleaner syntax. It's called [SuperLayout](https://github.com/lionheart/SuperLayout) and is available on Cocoapods. At the top of your source file, import `SuperLayout`:

```
import SuperLayout
```

And then in your layout block, use `~~`, `≤≤`, and `≥≥` to pin constraints:

```
override func updateConstraints() {
    let margins = contentView.layoutMarginsGuide

    subview1.leadingAnchor ~~ margins.leadingAnchor
    subview2.leadingAnchor ~~ margins.leadingAnchor

    super.updateConstraints()
}
```

ios 11+: let margins = contentView.directionalLayoutMargins
...
in case you need to adapt to LTR and RTL out of the box. I assume most folks do need that.

Comment: The app I was developing was for iOS 8 so I didn't try this solution, but I sure will! About your answer : AFAIK Anchors can't be "seen" in IB but it's indeed probably what it does in the shadows. Clearly if you want to it programmatically, yours is the right way. However, seeing that my solution worked for all those using IB, you should check that preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins is set to true on *both* the cell and its Content View when the constraint is set to the Content View's margins.

Comment: This is the solution that worked for me. My target is iOS 10+ and I am using Swift 4.1 in my project. Indeed setting the `preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins` property to true didn't work for me, neither programmatically nor via the interface builder. I am using layout constraints. Thanks @Dan Loewenherz for saving a lot of headaches!

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get cells with custom styles aligned with the standard cells by doing the following:

1. In the Document Outline, select the "Content View" for the cell with
   the custom style.
2. Go to the Size Inspector.
3. Under the "Layout Margins" dropdown, hit the little plus symbol next to "Preserve Superview Margins."
4. Select the iPad size class, which is "Regular Width x Regular Height."
5. Check the checkbox next to "Preserve Superview Margins."
6. Resolve any Auto Layout warnings by updating the frames.

This worked for me in Xcode 7; I'm hoping it will work in Xcode 6 as well.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! Unfortunately there's no such option in Xcode 6.

Comment: Darn! Sorry about that. Well, at least there will be an option to fix it in the future!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when testing on a iPad Air, OS 10.1.1. The table headers were indented much further than they should have been, and it was even worse in landscape orientation. But they were fine on iphones up to OS 11.

The surprising solution was the following line of code, just after the table was created (Sorry, I only work in C#, but it's easy to work out Obj-C and Swift equivalents):

```
myTableView.SeparatorInset = myTableView.SeparatorInset;
```

Then everything was indented as it should be!