# UITableViewCell layoutMargin and separatorInset not "in sync" when in PageSheet

Tags: swift, autolayout, uitableview

Simple scenario, but the problem is driving me crazy..

**What I want to achieve:**
UITableViewCell's contentView to be aligned with separatorInset in each and every scenario.

**Result:** The layoutMargin.left is different from separatorInset when shown in a Popover as page sheet (i.e. iPhone 6/6S Plus) with iOS 8.1-8.2 and iOS 9.x. iOS 8.3 and 8.4 work fine.

**Cell Settings:**

- preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins and contentView.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins are true
- autoLayout of Label is pinned to superView margins with constant 0

**Investigations:**
If found this post from matt, explaining the underlying problem a bit:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/29712427/844907

I implemented a layoutDidChange method to check the margins:

```
override func layoutMarginsDidChange() {
    debugPrint("layoutMarginsDidChange: ", layoutMargins.left, contentView.layoutMargins.left, separatorInset.left)
}
```

Some of the returned values after a few rotations from PageSheet to FullScreen:

> "layoutMarginsDidChange: " 16.0 16.0 20.0 ("real" popOver on 6+ with 8.2)
> "layoutMarginsDidChange: " 20.0 20.0 20.0 (FullScreen 6+ with 8.2)

Or on iPhone 6+ 9.3:

> FullScreen (both lines!):
>
> "layoutMarginsDidChange: " 8.0 8.0 20.0
>
> "layoutMarginsDidChange: " 20.0 20.0 20.0
>
> After rotation to pageSheet:
>
> "layoutMarginsDidChange: " 16.0 16.0 20.0

Last value is the separator.left, first two are the layoutMargins.left and contentView.layoutMargins.left.

Any idea how to fix this?

I though of setting layoutMargins.left to separatorInset.left but this doesn't felt right without knowing the source of the problem..

See images below:

[image: Fullscreen]
[image: Page Sheet]

Comment: @FrederikAWinkelsdorf, I am trying to answer this question today. Have you found an answer?

Comment: @SAHM No, unfortunately not. You can only workaround by setting layoutMargins and separatorInsets manually.