# iOS9 / Xcode 7 Custom Cell Label Alignment Issues

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios9, xcode7

I am having an issue with layouts in custom cells in Xcode in my iOS app since it updating to Xcode 7 and iOS 9 SDK.

On the example screenshot below, the custom cells that I have created with labels inside them are not aligning to the correct default inset/indent that the normal non-custom cells are at.

Specifically as you can see below, the cells in Section 1 are all very close to the left edge (custom cells), as is Cell 0 in Section 2 (Online label is too snug, and the switch is too far to the right), whereas Cells 1-3 in Section 2 (normal default style cells) have the correct default ~15px indent.

[image: Custom cell indents not working correctly]

**Previously it worked correct in iOS8 with Xcode 6.x, but not after the update....how can I solve this?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that this issue can be solved by using the accepted solution for this question here! Good luck and happy coding!

[UITableViewCell with autolayout left margin different on iPhone and iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27420888/uitableviewcell-with-autolayout-left-margin-different-on-iphone-and-ipad)