# XCode 7 with iOS 9.3 - Constraints works in iPhone simulator but when running in an iPad simulator a margin is added

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ipad, ios-simulator

I'm creating a very simple project, but I can't make the constraints work perfectly both in iPhones and iPad, there's this weird behavior when I execute the app in an iPad simulator (images below).

I read that there's some differences in the margins between iPhones and iPad.

It's seems like the problem is in the View Margins. I tried to put this code in my appDelegate:

```
UITableViewCell.appearance().preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = true
UITableViewCell.appearance().contentView.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = true
```

I found that in [UITableViewCell with autolayout left margin different on iPhone and iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27420888/uitableviewcell-with-autolayout-left-margin-different-on-iphone-and-ipad), but it doesn't work!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Silly Mistake, I didn't set in DEVICES to Universal.

[image]