# UITableViewCellStyleValue1 textLabel get different frame on 6plus and other devices

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I get a `TableView`.I use custom `cells` in some rows,and some `cells` use `UITableViewCellStyleValue1`.I set custom cell in `XIB` by `autoLayout`.

[image]

But on `iPhone` 6plus, `UITableViewCellStyleValue1` the textLabel.frame = (20 11; 45 18),the frame is (15 11; 45 18) on other devices.So you can see the label is not on the right place.

Is there a proper way to change the frame of `UITableViewCellStyleValue1` `textLabel`?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's something to do with a constraint to margin, if you change your leading constraint of your label for your custom cell to look the image below. Also this question looks similar to your problem, [UITableViewCell with autolayout left margin different on iPhone and iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27420888/uitableviewcell-with-autolayout-left-margin-different-on-iphone-and-ipad).

[image]

Comment: It would create a difference 0f 8 not 5

Comment: I didn't change any constraint of UITableViewCellStyleValue1,It just change automaticly on 6plus and 6s plus

Comment: Dharmendra you have a point, but I thought it's worth a try. Randall, so I would like you to check whether changing the constraint on your custom cell will help, not the standard UITableViewCell.