# Avoid extra leading margin for UITableViewCell under iOS 11

Tags: uitableview, ios11

All custom `UITableViewCells` which are compiled under iOS11 (Xcode 9) are getting an extra leading margin but not with iOS10 (Xcode 8). Please see the images.

iOS 10, compiled with Xcode 8

[image]

iOS 11, compiled with Xcode 9

[image]

How to get the iOS 10 behavior for devices with iOS 11 too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem using the answer to [UITableViewCell with autolayout left margin different on iPhone and iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31133547). Setting “Preserve Superview Margins” on both the table view cell and the content view it contains resolved the inconsistency between rendering in iOS 10 and iOS 11.

Answer (score 3):

Another workaround, in the opposite direction (i.e. having the same behaviour you had in iOS 10), would be to set `preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins` to false in the cell and the content view of your cell. For example, in you `UITableViewCell` subclass:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false
    contentView.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false
}
```

This way you recover the iOS 10 behaviour.